# dto and dao implementation

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

code on the click event of the button

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         

  String login, password;

   login = jTextField1.getText().trim();
   password = jTextField2.getText().trim();

    System.out.println("hello");   
    RegisterDAO r = new RegisterDAO();
    r.insert(login, password);


}
```

code for the dao class

```
 public class RegisterDAO {

 private String login, password;

public void insert(String login ,String password)
{
    this.login= login;
    this.password = password;

    RegisterDTO r = new RegisterDTO();
    r.setLogin(login);
    r.setPass(password);

 java.sql.Connection con = new DBConnection().getConnection();
   if (con!=null){
    System.out.println("the connection object is active ");

    PreparedStatement pst;
    String Q;
    int x=1;

    Q="insert into x(a,b) values(?,?)";
   try {
   pst=con.prepareStatement(Q);
   pst.setString(x++, login );
   pst.setString(x++,password);

   int a=pst.executeUpdate();
     System.out.println(a);

    }
    catch (Exception ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
//JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s, s, x, null);
}
```

my dto class

```
 public class RegisterDTO {
private String a;
private String b;
public void setLogin(String a)
{
    this.a = a ;
    System.out.println(a);
}
public String getLogin()
{
    return a;
}
public void setPass(String b)
{
    this.b = b;
    System.out.println(b);

}
public String  getPass()
{
    return b;
}
```

1)my problem is that i am not able to retain the values that is stored in the dto class by the setter and the getter methods . what are the ways to get the value using the dto.
i also want  to access the value on the on other   page but i am not able to get that value the print statement in the dto class shows that the value is stored in the variable 
the application i am creating is of the swing based and i don't know that is swing support the sessions management, if it support the session than help me to implement that.

2)i  want to know that the approch that i am following in the case  of the DAO and DTO is proper or not

3)i  want to know that to access the dto to the each and every page do i need to create the object of the dto to access that, if that is the case does it result in the ambiguity as the multiple object created

4)can i be able to directly access the value that is stored in the dto by the getter method( without data base access ). i have created the ret() method to retrieve the data from the data base in my dao class

```
    public void ret(String login  )
{
    login= this.login ; 

      java.sql.Connection con = new DBConnection().getConnection();
   if (con!=null){
    System.out.println("the connection object is active ");

    PreparedStatement pst;
    String Q;
    int x=1;

    Q="select * form x where a=?";
   try {
   pst=con.prepareStatement(Q);
       pst.setString(x++, login );


       ResultSet rs= null;      
        rs = pst.executeUpdate();


}
```

the above code result in the error that the result set is not able to handle the integer out of the executeUpdate() methods . do i need to cast for that purpose as i am not able to figure it out how the integer value is cast into the result set . i also want to know that how to access the individual fields as the result set displays the whole tuple . how the result set is able to store the values to the individual fields of the getter methods

Comment: *"the above code result in the error that the result set is not able to handle the integer out of the executeUpdate() methods"* This is because [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't return a ResultSet but an integer instead (see the API). I think you mean [executeQuery()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) which does return a ResultSet as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) My problem is that i am not able to retain the values that is
>   stored in the dto class by the setter and the getter methods . what
>   are the ways to get the value using the dto. i also want to access the
>   value on the on other page but i am not able to get that value the
>   print statement in the dto class shows that the value is stored in the
>   variable the application i am creating is of the swing based and i
>   don't know that is swing support the sessions management, if it
>   support the session than help me to implement that.

The DTO class is not persistent and there seems to be no link between it and the DTO. Since it is not persisting anything, then you will not be able to reload items back in the DTO class unless you go through the DAO class for storing/retrieving values.

> 2)I want to know that the approch that i am following in the case of
>   the DAO and DTO is proper or not

I do not think so. The DAO is a data access object, which is correct in your example since it yields functionality to perform the basic CRUD operations. On the other hand, I am pretty sure that your implementation of the DTO is incorrect. DTO (as far as memory serves) stands for Data Transfer Object. In short, it should represent a subset of the fields that the particular object has in the database so that you can use more lightweight objects to represent database entities. For instance, the `User` object in the database could have fields such as `PK`, `UID`, `DateCreated`, `DateModified`, `Name`, `Password_Hash`, etc. Your `UserDTO` would have less fields, such as `UID` and `Name`. The DAO layer would usually yield DTO objects.

> 3)i want to know that to access the dto to the each and every page do
>   i need to create the object of the dto to access that, if that is the
>   case does it result in the ambiguity as the multiple object created

Yes you will have to. An alternative method would be to use the `Singleton` data pattern to share and re-use the same DAO instance across all your classes.

> 4)can i be able to directly access the value that is stored in the dto
>   by the getter method( without data base access ). i have created the
>   ret() method to retrieve the data from the data base in my dao class

In this case the DTO class is either redundant or misleading. I would suggest you remove it.

As for your last question, I would recommend you take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html) Oracle tutorial for more information on how to operate with JDBC.